# Solve exception in Dispose method

Tags: c#

Is it possible to mark a exception as solved in Dispose method of Token class? E.g.:

```
//code before
using(var e = new Token()){
  //..
  throw new Exception();
  //..
}
//code after
```

What I need is to void exception and continue with code after.

It does not matter if Exception occurred. I know that I can use try/catch, but in this case, I would like to go around if it possible.

I am detecting exception in the by:

```
bool isExceptionOccurred = Marshal.GetExceptionPointers() != IntPtr.Zero || Marshal.GetExceptionCode() != 0;
```

Comment: What's the type of the exception? You could just catch the exception and do nothing with it.

Comment: "*I know that I can use try/catch, but in this case, I would like to go around if it possible.*" - Why? That seems like an odd requirement or desire. The straightforward (perhaps only?) answer would be a `try` with an empty `catch` block.

Comment: Try/catch is _the_ standard way to detect exceptions and decide whether to handle them or not.   What reasons do you have for not using the standard mechanism for error handling?

Comment: Or are you asking about code that would prevent the exception in the first place?  Like simple null-checking?

Comment: Token is some kind of atomic operation (e.g. transaction on application level). Atomic operation will be finished in Dispose method of Token class. When we finalized atomic operation, we need to know is exception occurred - because login depend on it. And because we don't publish complete solution, our client would like to have as simple as possible solution to use component.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do that is to use a catch block, because that's what it's there for. Don't try to shoehorn your business requirements into the language, use the language to write what you need.

Create an abstraction layer that handles your "don't leak exceptions" requirement. For example:

```
public sealed class ExceptionGuard<T>:IDisposable where T:IDisposable
{
    private readonly T instance;

    public bool ExceptionOccurred { get; private set; }

    public ExceptionGuard(T instance) { this.instance = instance; }

    public void Use(Action<T> useInstance)
    {
        try
        {
            useInstance(instance);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            this.ExceptionOccurred = true;
            // Hopefully do something with your exception
        }        
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            this.instance.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

After that, it's a fairly simple matter to consume and inspect.

```
var guard = new ExceptionGuard(new Token());

using (guard)
{
    guard.Use(token => /* Do something with your token */ );        
}

if (guard.ExceptionOccurred)
{
    // React accordingly to this
}
```